# plugin builder problem with compiling(probaly)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I m trying to make a new plugin with the use of plugin builder. But i stumbeled across a problem when following this [tutorial](http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/). I get stuck on the point that i have to compile the plugin.

With the use of OSGeoW shell i used this code in my plugin directory:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

There is no message in the shell that the command is executed. 
In QGIS i can see in my "manage and install plugins" screen that qgis know that my plugin is there but gives the error that the syntax is false. See image[image]

I didn't change anything in the plugin files. I m curently using qgis 2.14.3 and a Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Are u sure that you are in the correct catalog? Before you write

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

Write:

```
cd c:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\SaveAttributes
```

I think that [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) tutorial is really good for the introduction of qgis plugins..

Comment: i m sure that i m using the correct directory. my plugin is located in C:\Users\berend\.qgis2\python\plugins\ChangeMaxAndMinOfRaster.